# C# + OracleSQL - can't use parameters in CommandText

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I want to create simple login + registration form in C#, based on OracleSQL. I'm using Oracle's ManagedDataAccess Client (from NuGet).

I tried to use it like this:

```
OracleCommand query = db.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText = string.Format("insert into @tablename values(null, '@login', '@pwd', 0, null)");
query.Parameters.Add("@tablename", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("usersTableName"));
query.Parameters.Add(name: "@login", val: login);
query.Parameters.Add(name: "@pwd", val: HashPassword(pwd));
bool isCreated = (query.ExecuteReader().RecordsAffected > 0 ? true : false);
query.Dispose();
return isCreated;
```

^ btw there probably should be another way to make that bool. Probably it'd cast int to bool by itself.

The structure is quite simple there:

```
"USERS" 
(
"ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"USERNAME" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
"IS_LOGGED" NUMBER(1,0), 
"IP" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
)
```

That code failed. Tried with '@', colons, etc. If I even made it work, it added the record with "@login" username. Literally what I wrote in my parameter's name. Also, it says ORA-00903 error "Invalid table name" (it's probably it sends the name as "@tablename", though)...

Code worked this way:

```
string q = string.Format("insert into {0} values(null, '{1}', '{2}', 0, null)", 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("usersTableName"), login, HashPassword(pwd));
```

When I used this string as query's CommandText, it worked well. I don't like to keep it this way, especially because SQL injections thing.

I'm completely newbie when it comes to C#, so I probably made so many mistakes in such short code.

Comment: remove the quotes round the '@login' and '@pwd'

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for fast answer! Unfortunately, it didn't work like it should. Now I have ORA-00936 error - that there is no expression. I keep quotes, because @ login and @ pwd are strings.

Comment: yes, but the parameters should sort that out for you!  although https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx suggests that you should use : not @ ... maybe thats the answer

Comment: I tried with colons as well (it was my very first version) - still didn't work

Comment: Oracle's ManagedDataAccess Client supports table name parameter? Really?

Comment: Didnt spot that one @Serg but the parameter should work right for the rest.

Comment: @Serg Even if it didn't, I put it in CommandText as its part - it didn't help me with parameters' problem

Comment: A structure of string.Format method has to be like this. string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", textA, textB, textC); Hope you step foward.

Comment: @KayLee I do know about that, and string.Format is the only thing working for me right now. The problem is with Parameters.Add(), but thanks!

Comment: Okay, my bad. I modified that query a bit, and managed to make it work - thanks for all your help!

Now, I need to find a way to close a question :D

The answer was, actually, using a :login w/o quotes. I have no idea why it didn't work earlier, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table name and column name cannot be as a parameter. Because it prevents the Oracle SQL parser to parse the query and create execution plan.
You used '@tablename' parameter in your query text and you must remove this parameter and replace it by 'usersTableName' for example.
Using @ as parameter specifier is the correct way to define bind parameter in .Net environment (including C#) for any DBMS includindg Oracle. although using ':' is correct also for Oracle.

More info:

Using bind parameters recommended for improving performance and avoiding SQL injection. Improving performance is result of caching execution plan by Oracle then parameters cannot change the structure of a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind tablenames in Oracle SQL. You can instead do something like this (and remember to be aware of SQL injection when constructing SQL like this)

```
            OracleCommand query = db.CreateCommand();
        query.CommandText = string.Format("insert into " + 
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("usersTableName") +
            " values(null, :login, :pwd, 0, null)");
        query.Parameters.Add(":login", login);
        query.Parameters.Add(":pwd", HashPassword(pwd));
        bool isCreated = (query.ExecuteReader().RecordsAffected > 0 ? true : false);
```